# duplicate local variable and variables cannot be resolved

Tags: java

I'm being given three different errors in my java code, any help?

Error one: Duplicate local variable product.

```
int product = input.nextInt();
```

Error 2: productTotal cannot be resolved to a variable.

```
System.out.printf( "%10.2f\n",  productTotal );
```

Error 3: salesPersonTotal cannot be resolved to a variable.

```
System.out.printf( "%14.2f",  salesPersonTotal[ column ]);
```

Java Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
class TotalSales
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        
        double sales[][] = new double [ 5 ] [ 4 ];
        
        System.out.print( "Enter salesperson number (-1 to end): " );
        int person = input.nextInt();
        
        while ( person != -1 )
        {
            System.out.print( "Enter product number: ");
            int product = input.nextInt();
            
            while ( person != -1 )
            {
                System.out.print( "Enter product number: " );
                int product = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print( "Enter sales amount: ");
                double amount = input.nextDouble();
                
                if ( person >= 1 && person <5 &&
                product >= 1 && product <6 && amount >=0 )
                    sales[ product - 1 ] [ person -1 ] += amount;
                else
                    System.out.println("Invalid input!" );
                
                System.out.print( "Enter slaesperson number (-1 to end): " );
                person = input.nextInt();
            }
            
            double salesPersonTotal [] = new double[ 4 ];
            
            for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++ )
                salesPersonTotal[ column ] = 0;
            System.out.printf( "%8s%14s%14s%14s%14s%10s\n",
                    "Product", "Salesperson 1", "Salesperson 2",
                    "Salesperson 3", "Salesperson 4", "Total" );
            for ( int row = 0; row < 5; row++ )
            {
                double productTotal = 0.0;
                System.out.printf( "%8d", (row+1));
                
                for ( int column = 0; column < 4; column ++ ) {
                    System.out.printf( "%14.2f", sales[row] [column]);
                    productTotal += sales[row][column];
                    salesPersonTotal[column] += sales[row][column];
                }
                System.out.printf( "%10.2f\n", productTotal );
            }
            
            System.out.printf( "%10.2f\n",  productTotal );
        }
        
        System.out.printf( "%8s", "Total" );
        
        for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++ )
            System.out.printf( "%14.2f",  salesPersonTotal[ column ]);
        
        System.out.println();
                }
            }
```

Additional Info:

> Problem: (TotalSales) Use a two-dimensional array to solve the following problem: A company has four salespeople (1 to 4) who sell five different products (1 to 5). Once a day, each salesperson passes in a slip for each type of product sold. Each slip contains the following:
>
> a) The salesperson number (1 to 4)
> b) The product number
> c) The total dollar value of the product (1 to 5) sold that day. Thus, each salesperson passes in between 0 and 5 sales slips per day.
>
> Assume that the information from all the slips for last month is available. Write an application that will read all this information for last month's sales and summarize the total sales by salesperson and by product. All totals should be stored in the two-dimensional array sales. After processing all the information for a month (all the records in the data file), display the results in tabular format, with each column representing a particular product and each row representing a particular salesperson. Cross-total each row to get the total sales of each product for the month. Cross-total each column to get the total sales by salesperson for the month. Your tabular output should include these cross-totals to the right of the totaled rows and to the bottom of the totaled columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make variables global and you can declare a variable only once:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner; 
class TotalSales
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        double sales[][] = new double [ 5 ] [ 4 ];

        double productTotal = 0.0;
        double salesPersonTotal [] = new double[ 4 ];

        System.out.print( "Enter salesperson number (-1 to end): " );
        int person = input.nextInt();

        while ( person != -1 )
        {
            System.out.print( "Enter product number: ");
            int product = input.nextInt();

            while ( person != -1 )
            {
                System.out.print( "Enter product number: " );
                product = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print( "Enter sales amount: ");
                double amount = input.nextDouble();

                if ( person >= 1 && person <5 &&
                product >= 1 && product <6 && amount >=0 )
                    sales[ product - 1 ] [ person -1 ] += amount;
                else
                    System.out.println("Invalid input!" );

                System.out.print( "Enter slaesperson number (-1 to end): " );
                person = input.nextInt();
            }



            for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++ )
                salesPersonTotal[ column ] = 0;
            System.out.printf( "%8s%14s%14s%14s%14s%10s\n",
                    "Product", "Salesperson 1", "Salesperson 2",
                    "Salesperson 3", "Salesperson 4", "Total" );
            for ( int row = 0; row < 5; row++ )
            {
                System.out.printf( "%8d", (row+1));

                for ( int column = 0; column < 4; column ++ ) {
                    System.out.printf( "%14.2f", sales[row] [column]);
                    productTotal += sales[row][column];
                    salesPersonTotal[column] += sales[row][column];
                }
                System.out.printf( "%10.2f\n", productTotal );
            }

            System.out.printf( "%10.2f\n",  productTotal );
        }

        System.out.printf( "%8s", "Total" );

        for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++ )
            System.out.printf( "%14.2f",  salesPersonTotal[ column ]);

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! These answers were very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You declared product twice, and you refer to productTotal and salesPersonTotal when they are out of scope. Try changing the second product variable's name (or use the same variable if that's okay with your solution), and try declaring productTotal and salesPersonTotal one scope block up.

Answer (score 0):

Any variables created inside of a loop are local to the loop. This means that once you exit the loop, the variable can no longer be accessed. If you want to use the variable after you left the loop, then you have to declare it before beforehand in the outer loop or method scope.